# Filter Object Array values based on user input

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the object array values based on user input.

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaa5omox/24/):

```js
// Copied from https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js
const reduce = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Array.prototype.reduce);
const isEnumerable = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable);
const concat = Function.bind.call(Function.call, Array.prototype.concat);
const keys = Reflect.ownKeys;
if (!Object.values) {
  Object.values = function values(O) {
    return reduce(keys(O), (v, k) => concat(v, typeof k === 'string' && isEnumerable(O, k) ? [O[k]] : []), []);
  };
}

// Copied code ends here;

let data = {
  Belgien: [{
    code: "BRU",
    name: "Bryssel",
    aliases: "Bryssel,BRU,Belgien"
  }],
  Cypern: [{
      code: "LCA",
      name: "Larnaca",
      aliases: "Larnaca,LCA,Cypern,Ayia Napa,Protaras,Fig Tree Bay,Larnaca"
    },
    {
      code: "PFO",
      name: "Paphos",
      aliases: "Paphos,PFO,Cypern"
    }
  ]
}

let userInput = "lar";

let filteredData = Object.values(data).map(values => values.filter(value =>
  value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) !== -1));

console.log(filteredData);
```

The issue is that I get the values properly filtered, but I do not get the keys associated with these values, in this example the countries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a lot of experience posting questions on stackoverflow. This is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/kaa5omox/24/

Comment: Added polyfill as Object.values was throwing error. If not required, please revert the edit

Comment: @Ayoub You can just update OP's fiddle

Comment: ```let filtered = Object.keys(data).map(countryName => {
  const matches = data[countryName].filter(val => val.name.toLowerCase().match(userInput));
  return matches.length ? ({[countryName]: matches}) : null;
}).filter(v => v)```

Comment: Thank you guys. Much appreciated! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` and filter the data using the functions `filter` and `indexOf`.

This alternative uses the function `Object.keys` to be able to recover the desired key.

```js
let data = {  Belgien: [{    code: "BRU",    name: "Bryssel",    aliases: "Bryssel,BRU,Belgien"  }],  Cypern: [{      code: "LCA",      name: "Larnaca",      aliases: "Larnaca,LCA,Cypern,Ayia Napa,Protaras,Fig Tree Bay,Larnaca"    },    {      code: "PFO",      name: "Paphos",      aliases: "Paphos,PFO,Cypern"    }  ]},
    userInput = "lar",
    filteredData = Object.keys(data).reduce((a, k) => {
      a[k] = data[k].filter(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) > -1);
      return a;
    }, {});

console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the keys and return an object with only filtered data.

```js
var data = { Belgien: [{ code: "BRU", name: "Bryssel", aliases: "Bryssel,BRU,Belgien" }], Cypern: [{ code: "LCA", name: "Larnaca", aliases: "Larnaca,LCA,Cypern,Ayia Napa,Protaras,Fig Tree Bay,Larnaca" }, { code: "PFO", name: "Paphos", aliases: "Paphos,PFO,Cypern" }] },
    userInput = "lar",
    filteredData = Object.keys(data).reduce((r, k) => {
        var temp = data[k].filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().includes(userInput));
        if (temp.length) {
            r[k] = temp;
        }
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the job done using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like this:

```
let filteredData = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, values) => {
  const value = values[1].filter(value =>
      value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput) !== -1),
    key = values[0];
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```